# Trackpad Mouse click not responsive

Tags: unity, mouse, touchpad, trackpad

After trying for a while finally managed to run Ubuntu on my Acer D255 e, using seagate external HDD. All is working fine apart from mouse. Although trackpad allow me to select program and open application. I cannot click select within application, the only way I can click select is using a combination of tab/arrow keys/enter when within an application.

In universal access under the pointer and clicking:
Mouse key is OFF
Simulated secondary click ON
Hover click OFF

In mouse and touchpad
Under all setting 
General: primary button left/ double click half way
Touch pad: ON Slow 1/3 of the way
Only Tap to click is selected

My system.

Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Memory 2GB
Intel Atom CPU N555 @1,50GHz x 4
32-Bit

Any pointers on how to fully enable trackpad and mouse click? So that I can fully enjoy the wonder of using Ubuntu beautiful features. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, removing and reloading the trackpad/mouse driver appear to fix the problem temporarily.

Open a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T) and run

Code:
sudo modprobe -rv psmouse 
sudo modprobe -v psmouse

Answer (score 0):

To set various options of Synaptics touch pads, take a look at
[`man synclient`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/synclient.1.html)
and
[`man xinput`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xinput.1.html)

For exaple, the following options are available on an Asus eeepc:

Device driver level options:

```
$ synclient 
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 1775
    RightEdge               = 5505
    TopEdge                 = 1648
    BottomEdge              = 4602
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 243
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 110
    HorizScrollDelta        = 110
    VertEdgeScroll          = 1
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0361598
    TouchpadOff             = 0
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 1
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 1
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 27
    VertHysteresis          = 27
    ClickPad                = 0
```

X server level options:

```
$ xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
        Device Enabled (135):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (137): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        Device Accel Profile (260):     1
        Device Accel Constant Deceleration (261):       2.500000
        Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (262):       1.000000
        Device Accel Velocity Scaling (263):    12.500000
        Synaptics Edges (264):  1775, 5505, 1648, 4602
        Synaptics Finger (265): 25, 30, 0
        Synaptics Tap Time (266):       180
        Synaptics Tap Move (267):       243
        Synaptics Tap Durations (268):  180, 180, 100
        Synaptics ClickPad (269):       0
        Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (270):  75
        Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (271):    282
        Synaptics Two-Finger Width (272):       7
        Synaptics Scrolling Distance (273):     110, 110
        Synaptics Edge Scrolling (274): 1, 0, 0
        Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (275):   1, 0
        Synaptics Move Speed (276):     1.000000, 1.750000, 0.036160, 0.000000
        Synaptics Off (277):    0
        Synaptics Locked Drags (278):   0
        Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (279):   5000
        Synaptics Tap Action (280):     2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
        Synaptics Click Action (281):   1, 1, 0
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling (282):     0
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (283):    0.100000
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (284):     0
        Synaptics Circular Pad (285):   0
        Synaptics Palm Detection (286): 0
        Synaptics Palm Dimensions (287):        10, 200
        Synaptics Coasting Speed (288): 20.000000, 50.000000
        Synaptics Pressure Motion (289):        30, 160
        Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (290): 1.000000, 1.000000
        Synaptics Resolution Detect (291):      1
        Synaptics Grab Event Device (292):      1
        Synaptics Gestures (293):       1
        Synaptics Capabilities (294):   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
        Synaptics Pad Resolution (295): 136, 80
        Synaptics Area (296):   0, 0, 0, 0
        Synaptics Noise Cancellation (297):     27, 27
        Device Product ID (255):        2, 7
        Device Node (256):      "/dev/input/event6"
```